# Fullcalendar start and end date no picking

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement full calendar js plugin but the events default to the  first hour on the callendar that is from 12 a.m to 1 a.m . 
Below is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>appointments/get_appointmentss',
                error: function () {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
            // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
            eventRender: function (event) {

                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                    event.allDay = false;
                }

            },
            loading: function (bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });



    });

</script>
```

The returned value in json encode is below :

```
[{"title":"Rabbi Less Brown Motivation","allDay":"false","start":"2015-06-17 14:00:00","end":"2015-06-17 15:00:00"},{"title":"Miss Mary Wochete Sinaida","allDay":"false","start":"2015-06-02 14:15:30","end":"2015-06-02 14:30:25"},{"title":"Lt Col Robirt Sharma Monk","allDay":"false","start":"2015-06-18 08:00:00","end":"2015-06-18 09:00:00"}]
```

The start and end day are saved on mysql data type datetime . 
What am I not doing right for the information to display within the  stipulated time ?

Comment: You can't change the `allDay` property in the eventRender function. You have to process this before you add them to the calendar.